# Switch between connection string at runtime

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005

I need to switch between some databases at the same time (using VB.net). As far as I know, I must create some connection Strings and use them in different conditions.

For example

```
If ( condition )  then 
  use connection String 1
elseif (condition)  then 
  use connection String 2 
end if
```

Can anyone help me how to handle this?
I'm using MSSQL 2005 and VB.net

Comment: What about the database, it is on same machine in both cases or any other server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET, you need to add a module and write few functions there. And use these function to establish and close connection to Database.

**Variables:**
ConnectionString variables (both)

**Functions:**

- Close_Database_Connection(): If connection is open then close it.
- Create_Database_Connection(condition_param): Here you put your
  conditions in If Else Structure. Like:

**Code:**

```
If ( condition ) Then
        use connection String 1 
    ElseIf (condition) Then
        use connection String 2 
    End If
```

Use this "Create_Database_Connection(condition_param)" Method where you need to establish connection in code depending upon you conditional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a variable outside the `If-Else` condition. Try something like this,

```
Dim ConnectionStr As String = String.empty
If (condition) Then
    ConnectionStr = 'conString 1'
ElseIf (condition) Then
    ConnectionStr = 'conString 2'
Else
    ConnectionStr = 'others....'
End if

' ConnectionStr hold your latest connection string
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.